# SOLVED: Why am I having the errors below with updating package: rlang when I have closed everything out and even removed the old package?

Tags: r, r-package, rlang

SOLVED: See solution in answers below

I was trying to install a package and it said I need the latest version of 'rlang'

So i went to update it and I get the message

Warning in install.packages :
cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
restored ‘rlang’

So I tried restarting R and closing all projects etc., I tried restarting my computer....no go

Next I tried remove.packeges(rlang)

It said it can't remove it, but now I can't find rlang in my packeges.

I tried to install rlang and I get the same message as above as if I still have it installed

I run library(rlang) and get the following messages:
Error in library("rlang") : there is no package called ‘rlang’

So now i don't have rlang? but my computer can't remove the latest version...which isn't there? I have restarted the program quite a few times and have everything closed that could have rlang open.

install.packages("rlang")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rlang_0.4.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1149015 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
restored ‘rlang’

The downloaded binary packages are in

[enter image description here][1]

please see picture below showing I do not have rlang installed
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CliaA.png

Comment: This might be an issue with a previously loaded workspace. Check your settings to make sure you always start with a clean workspace: https://r4epis.netlify.app/welcome/#configuring-rstudio

Comment: Ok, so I double checked this, and I did not have it to start clean everytime. I switched it to never restore .Rdata, but unfortunately the problem is persisting

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever search tools you use to find any possible instance of "rlang."  Your problem sounds like it got installed locally rather than globally, or vice versa, and that's why `remove.packages` may not see it.

The idea is to check whether there's more than one location where R/libraries directories might exist, and purge `rlang` from all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, ive been working on this since you posted and have deleted quite a few files I have found elsewhere. The problem is still persisting, but I am continuing to look to find other files.

Comment: THIS WORKED thanks so much I finally found the file that was holding me up. I deleted it and it installed. Thanks!!!